# How to make array of inherited objects - Java

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

I have abstract class Animal and inheritance classes Fish and Dog.
I need to create various objects of fish and dogs and give them names and breeds and also make methods of the way they move.
Finally i need to create an array of them and do 4 random prints that will show their name and breed.

**Main Class:**

```
public class JavaApplication38 {


public static void main(String[] args) {


   Animal[] arr = new Animal[20];

    arr[0] = new Fish("Riby", "Sea Fish");
    arr[1] = new Dog("Any", "Great Dane");
    arr[2] = new Fish("Ribytsa", "River fish");
    arr[3] = new Dog("Jackie", "Pug");
    arr[4] = new Fish("Bobi", "Mix");
    arr[5] = new Dog("Ruby", "Labrador");    

    }

}
```

**Animal class**

```
public abstract class  Animal {

  public Animal(String name, String breed){

  } 



   public Animal(){
   }

   public abstract void moving();

}
```

**Dog class**

```
Public class Dog extends Animal{


private String breed;
private String name;

public Dog(){
}

 public Pas(String name, String breed){
     this.name = name;
     this.breed =breed;
}


@Override
public void moving() {
    System.out.print("Walk\n");
}
```

}

**Fish class**

```
public class Fish extends Animal {


private String breed;


private String name;

public Fish(){

}

public Fish(String name, String breed){
    this.name = name;
    this.breed= breed;
}

@Override
public void moving(){
    System.out.print("Swims\n");
}
```

}

**The question is, what do i have to write in a loop  to print names and breeds via array?**

Comment: Any particular reason you're not putting `breed` and `name` into the abstract `Animal` class?

Comment: for sure you should move those fields to super class and treat every entry as Animal instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that you defined `name` and `breed` separately in each subclass of `Animal`. You need to make `name` and `breed` instance variables in `Animal`. That way, Java knows that every single Animal has a `name` and `breed`.

```
public abstract class Animal {
    private String name;
    private String breed;

    public Animal(String name, String breed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public getName() { return name; }
    public getBreed() { return breed; }

    public abstract void moving();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog(String name, String breed) {
        super(name, breed);
    }

    @Override
    public void moving(){
        System.out.print("Walks\n");
    }
}

public class Fish extends Animal {
    public Fish(String name, String breed) {
        super(name, breed);
    }

    @Override
    public void moving(){
        System.out.print("Swims\n");
    }
}
```

Now you can print the `name` and `breed` for any `Animal`, whether it's a `Dog` or `Fish`.

```
Animal[] arr = new Animal[6];

arr[0] = new Fish("Riby", "Sea Fish");
arr[1] = new Dog("Any", "Great Dane");
arr[2] = new Fish("Ribytsa", "River fish");
arr[3] = new Dog("Jackie", "Pug");
arr[4] = new Fish("Bobi", "Mix");
arr[5] = new Dog("Ruby", "Labrador");

for (Animal a : arr) {
   System.out.println(a.getName() + " " + a.getBreed());
   a.moving();
}
```

Comment: arr[0] = new Fish("someName", "someBreed"); means that name and breed are assigned to fish constructor not animal constructor. When i compile it, it gives me null null for name and breed.

Comment: Whoops! You're right. I forgot to add constructors for Dog and Fish. I added them to the example. They accept a name and breed and then pass them to the superclass (Animal) constructor.